# Oracle Modify statement - error

Tags: oracle

I added a new column in my table.

```
ALTER TABLE neue_buch modify preis not null;
```

and I have got this error:

```
Error starting at line 40 in command:
ALTER TABLE neue_buch
modify preis not null
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-02296: cannot enable (S1885872.) - null values found
02296. 00000 - "cannot enable (%s.%s) - null values found"
*Cause:    an alter table enable constraint failed because the table
           contains values that do not satisfy the constraint.
*Action:   Obvious
```

What wrong with my MODIFY STATEMENT.?

many thanks in advance,

magidu

Answer (score 6):

The error message is telling you that there are some rows in `NEUE_BUCH` where the `PREIS` column is NULL.  You will need to modify those rows to have non-NULL values before you can create this NOT NULL constraint.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Remove the NULLs - e.g. update the rows that are NULL to have some value; or delete the rows.
2. Make the constraint non-validated for existing data - this will cause the constraint to only fail for newly inserted or updated rows.

   ```
   ALTER TABLE neue_buch MODIFY preis NOT NULL NOVALIDATE;
   ```

Both approaches have pros and cons. Option 1 is better for performance, because the CBO can rely on the constraint when optimizing queries. However, if you simply *don't know* what the NULLs should be, you might be tempted to replace them with a "null value indicator", i.e. a magic value - for example, for a column that has only positive integers you might replace the NULLs with -1 or something - but this has its own disadvantages. Option 2 may be preferable in this sort of instance to avoid having to use magic values.

Answer (score 0):

ALTER TABLE AG_PARTICELLE_AZIENDA MODIFY SEZIONE NOT NULL;
ORA-02296: impossibile abilitare (TRACKER.) - trovati valori non appropriati

nella tabella AG_PARTICELLE_AZIENDA alcuni valori di SEZIONE sono a null!

devo fare:

1)update AG_PARTICELLE_AZIENDA
  set sezione = null;

2)commit;

3)ALTER TABLE AG_PARTICELLE_AZIENDA MODIFY SEZIONE NOT NULL;

non ho capito il messaggio di errore!
qualcquno può aiutarmi?
grazie
ugo montorsi mail:ugo.montorsi@sin.it